# Blender - commands in C# C++

Tags: c#, c++, blender, game-maker-studio-2

I got a task to establish GMS2 -> Blender one way communication. Dll extending GMS2 needs to be written either in C# or C++. Problem with Blender is that it has no ports like Maya has. So I tought about a solution via sockets but not sure if that is the right way.

**I don't request any code**, just herebly asking for a pointer (pun).

Comment: `int *pointerForYou;` there you go (pun).

Comment: @AndreasBjørnHassingNielsen I know, we should not use them, but shouldn't this be a `void` pointer to be more helpful?

Comment: Take a look at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41533/how-to-remotely-run-a-python-script-in-an-existing-blender-instance . If interactive communication is required, you can use [callbacks](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.handlers.html), but it may be tricky.

Comment: Geuss this will be more chained than expected. oO     
gms->c++->python->blender

Comment: @SimplexRPGEngineemployee you can send commands from c++ or c#, but on blender's side python is the only option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blender uses python to create addons, a python addon can be created that opens a socket and alters the internal data. One example would be the [network render](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/netrender/) addon that is included with blender. You can also use the subprocess module to pipe data from an external program, see [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/45731/935).

If you need to use C/C++ within the addon, you have several options. An addon for blender is a standard python module - with some required methods and properties. A python module can be a [dynamic library](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) compiled from C/C++. You can also use [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) to access standard libraries from python code. Another option is to create a basic addon and use [cython](http://cython.org) to turn it into C code which you can then add your code to, [cube surfer](https://github.com/Pyroevil/CubeSurfer) and [animation nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes) are example addons that use cython to compile a shared library.